# How to disable Js merge for admin

Tags: magento2, javascript

**How to make disable JavaScript merge only for Admin panel?**

**Is it possible to make on coding level?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to achieve this I had to create a plugin for the admin area only and change the methods that read the settings.

Even if you have the possibility to choose different values on default and store view levels, the class that reads these settings values is not using the correct store code, and always using the store view level value.

The solution is to create a module, and add a `di.xml` for adminhtml area to forcely use the desired settings. The core class responsible for this is `Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Config`

Let's make a plugin for that:

1. Create the module along with `registration.php` and `etc/module.xml` files
2. Create the adminhtml di.xml file

`app/code/NameSpace/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Config">
        <plugin name="mergeminify_asset_config" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\View\Asset\Config" />
    </type>
</config>
```

3. Create the plugin class
   `app/code/[NameSpace]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/View/Asset/Config.php`

with the following content:

```
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class Config
{
    protected $_registry;
    /**
     * XML path for CSS files merge configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_MERGE_CSS_FILES = 'dev/css/merge_css_files';

    /**
     * XML path for JavaScript files merge configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_MERGE_JS_FILES = 'dev/js/merge_files';

    /**
     * XML path for asset minification adapter configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_JS_BUNDLING = 'dev/js/enable_js_bundling';

    /**
     * XML path for HTML minification configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_MINIFICATION_HTML = 'dev/template/minify_html';

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Check whether merging of CSS files is on
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterisMergeCssFiles()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_MERGE_CSS_FILES,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            0 // Force default value
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check whether bundling of JavScript files is on
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterisBundlingJsFiles()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_JS_BUNDLING,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            0 // Force default value
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check whether merging of JavScript files is on
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterisMergeJsFiles()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_MERGE_JS_FILES,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            0 // Force default value
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check whether minify of HTML is on
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterisMinifyHtml()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_MINIFICATION_HTML,
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            0 // Force default value
        );
    }
}
```

This way the backend will always use the default value and the frontend will use the store view value

Answer (score 6):

Try below extension:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Asset\Config">
        <plugin name="mergeminify_asset_config" type="[VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\View\Asset\Config" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> 4. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Plugin/View/Asset/Config.php

```
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Plugin\View\Asset;

use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class Config
{
    protected $_registry;
    /**
     * XML path for CSS files merge configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_MERGE_CSS_FILES = 'dev/css/merge_css_files';

    /**
     * XML path for JavaScript files merge configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_MERGE_JS_FILES = 'dev/js/merge_files';

    /**
     * XML path for asset minification adapter configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_JS_BUNDLING = 'dev/js/enable_js_bundling';

    /**
     * XML path for HTML minification configuration
     */
    const XML_PATH_MINIFICATION_HTML = 'dev/template/minify_html';

    /**
     * @var ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Default store view code
     */
    const DEFAULT_STORE = 'default';

    /**
     * State
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\State
     */
    protected $state;

    protected $storeScope = null;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\App\State $state
    ) {
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    public function afterisMergeCssFiles()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_MERGE_CSS_FILES,
            $this->getStoreScope()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check whether bundling of JavScript files is on
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterisBundlingJsFiles()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_JS_BUNDLING,
            $this->getStoreScope()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check whether merging of JavScript files is on
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterisMergeJsFiles()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_MERGE_JS_FILES,
            $this->getStoreScope()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Check whether minify of HTML is on
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function afterisMinifyHtml()
    {
        return (bool)$this->scopeConfig->isSetFlag(
            self::XML_PATH_MINIFICATION_HTML,
            $this->getStoreScope()
        );
    }

    /**
    * Check store scope is admin
    *
    * @return bool
    */
    public function getStoreScope()
    {
        if($this->storeScope == null) {
            $this->storeScope = (($this->state->getAreaCode() == \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML) ? self::DEFAULT_STORE : ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        }
        return $this->storeScope;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ayo baki market ma :)

Answer (score 1):

Without doing code,you can this.

First goto `admin>Store>Configuration>Advance>Developer` Then Select current scope ***Default Config***.

[image]

Then goto  `Make JavaScript Settings and Merge JavaScript Files` select it value to **NO**

This changes remove merge from all  area both ***frontend and admin***.

Now,  goto `admin>Store>Configuration>Advance>Developer>Make JavaScript Settings` Then Select current scope ***Main Website***.

Then change **`Merge JavaScript Files`** select it value to **Yes**

Then

flush magento cache and

run static content deploy: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

This solution will only disable js merge for admin

Comment: your solution is not working for me. :(

Comment: Yeah seems like it should work but it doesn't Admin still minified for some reason.